# Finding a maximum for a solution from NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I have the given model for SIR influenza epidemic:

```
 b=3.3925;
    k=2.95;
 n=157759 ;
 equationS=s'[t]==-b*s[t] i[t]/n
    equationI=i'[t]==b *s[t]i[t]/n- k*i[t]
    equationR=r'[t]==k i[t]
    solution=NDSolve[{equationS,equationI,equationR,s[0]==157756,i[0]==3,r[0]==0.0000},{s,r,i},{t,100}];
    solutionI=First[i/.solution];
    p1=Plot[{solutionI[t]},{t,0,100},PlotRange->{0,2000},PlotStyle->{Blue,Red,Magenta},
    PlotLegends->{Original_parameters}]
```

which gives the following plot

[image]

Since this is a numerical solution, and it is not based on data, I am not sure on how to find the total of infected individuals, $i_{tot}$, of the function $i(t)$. I am also looking for $i_{max}$ and $t_{max}$, for $i(t)$. The latter I though of using

NMaximize or FindMaximum, but neither work.

Any ideas what can be done to find these three values?

Thanks

Comment: `NMaximize[{solutionI@t, 0 < t < 100}, t]`

Comment: be careful with your legend. I would prefer `PlotLegends -> "Original_parameters"`

Comment: Documentation for `InterpolatingFunction` says you can take derivatives of that.  Plot that derivative and use the usual cautions. `FindRoot[D[solutionI[t],t],{t,15}]` returns `{t->17.1624}`

Comment: A straightforward `FindMaximum[solutionI[t], t]` also works. How did you use `NMaximize` and `FindMaximum`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

ClearAll["Global`*"]

b = 3.3925 // Rationalize;
k = 2.95 // Rationalize;
n = 157759;
equationS = s'[t] == -b*s[t] i[t]/n;
equationI = i'[t] == b*s[t] i[t]/n - k*i[t];
equationR = r'[t] == k i[t];

solution = 
  NDSolve[{equationS, equationI, equationR, s[0] == 157756, 
    i[0] == 3, r[0] == 0}, {s, r, i}, {t, 0, 100}];

solutionI[t_?NumericQ] := First[i /. solution][t];

total = NIntegrate[solutionI[t], {t, 0, 100}]

(* 13321.6 *)

{max, arg} = NMaximize[{solutionI[t], 0 < t < 100}, t]

(* {1407.08, {t -> 17.1624}} *)
```

Plotting,

```
p1 = Plot[i[t] /. solution, {t, 0, 100},
  PlotRange -> All,
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
    Point[{t /. arg, max}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid $I_\text{total}$ isn't defined like this. Check e.g. p9 of this: http://web.simmons.edu/~grigorya/390/projects/Charlotte-Kaitlin_Epidemics.pdf

Comment: Actually the total estimated 13321.6 seems about right to me, but I cannot tell if there is a better procedure.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon xzcdz has a good point here which is reflected when the the k-factor is quite large. I tried the model you wrote with k-factor of 5.9, and then the $i_{tot}<i_{max}$, which makes no sense. So your model is good as long as k-factor is low. That link is actually useful, however, I found another alternative, but it does not give a sensible answer $Integrate[First[i /. solution][t], {t, 0, 100}] / i[0]$

Answer (score 1):

Although Bob's answer is already correct, I'd like to present you some interesting trick, which might be useful when facing more complicated and time-consuming problems.

Many know that `Derivative` can be applied to directly obtain the derivatives of a `InterpolatingFunction`, for example try this with your code: `solutionI'`. However, `Derivative` can even be used to give anti-derivative:
`Derivative[-1][solutionI]`  give the integral directly from the `InterpolatingFunction`.

Another trick is that a more flexible grammar could be used when specifying the dependent variables in `NDSolve`. Here, `Derivative[-1][i][100]` directly give the result of the anti-derivative value at t=100.

The third trick is detecting the maximum on-the-fly inside NDSolve, with `WhenEvent`: `WhenEvent[i'[t] <= 0, Print[t, i[t]]]`.

Combining those tricks above:

````
b = 3.3925;
k = 2.95;
n = 157759;
equationS = s'[t] == -b*s[t] i[t]/n
equationI = i'[t] == b*s[t] i[t]/n - k*i[t]
equationR = r'[t] == k i[t]
solution = 
  NDSolve[{equationS, equationI, equationR, s[0] == 157756, i[0] == 3,
     r[0] == 0.0000,
    WhenEvent[i'[t] <= 0, {max, arg} = {t, i[t]}]},
   {s, r, i, Derivative[-1][i][100]}, {t, 100}];
solutionI = First[i /. solution];
p1 = Plot[{solutionI[t]}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> {0, 2000}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Magenta}, 
  PlotLegends -> {Original_parameters}]

{max, arg, solution[[1, -1]]}
```
````

Comment: I wonder if this can answer the issue we get when k=5.9, which gives the wrong number of infected over the  whole period.